# Angular reactive form, Dynamic validator not updating control validity

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder, angular-validation, angular-validator

So I have a form where a control is required only if another control has a value,  for this I created the following structure

```
 profileGroup = this.fb.group({
username: [''],
address: [
  '',
  [
    (control: AbstractControl) => {
      if (this.profileGroup?.get('username')?.value) {
        return (Validators.required)(control);
      }
      return (Validators.nullValidator)(control);
    },
  ],
],
```

});

this function works well, once the `username`  control gets a value, a `Validators.required` is added to the `address` control. However, despite the validator being added, the validity of the `address` control doesn't update so the control is still marked as `valid`.

If possible I would like to avoid using something like

```
this.profileGroup.get('username')?.valueChanges.subscribe(val=>{
  this.profileGroup.get('address')?.updateValueAndValidity()
})
```

since there may be dynamic controls that I don't know the name of, and don't want to set an observable for each of them.

Here's a stack blitz of a working example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-formbuilder-example-m8qjq8?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: `updateValueAndValidity()` is an AbstractControl class method, I guess you can just run this method for `this.profileGroup` and it should work, let me know how you go

Comment: What happens when you start inserting a value into address field, does the control shows as valid if you delete what you typed? Since you're setting the address validator only when username is inserted, what stops the user to first insert his address and after that his username? How will you handle that? Not sure if you're willing and if it fits your needs, but I'd suggest you add required validator to both fields on init and at submit handle the invalid states (error msgs or css changes, whatever) - after all the expected valid form will have both the username and address fields filled.

Comment: @DeepakJha you mean insert that in the function of the validator? nope it doesn't work

Comment: @MishaMashina Yes, the control is correctly marked as invalid if I type something and then clear it. It doesn't matter if the address control has a value despite username being empty, but if username has something address must be required

Comment: Reading your comments, is it the case that you're getting the form field elements' names from some service that's not under your control, like from some API?

Comment: Kinda, Not exactly from some API but from the database as a list, and that list can be modifid by some users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this function works well, once the username control gets a value, a Validators.required is added to the address control. However, despite the validator being added, the validity of the address control doesn't update so the control is still marked as valid.

Well, exactly that's not what happens. You have defined a `custom` validator for `address` FormControl, which gets executed when the `address` FormControl value is updated. (**PS:** It's not a dynamic validator)

When you update the `username`, the validators associated with it and its ancestors (profileGroup in your case) are called, the sibling FormControl validators are not triggered.

When you execute the below code, you are manually executing the validators associated with `address` FormControl, and that doesn't update the FormControl validity. It simply executes the validators associated with the FormControl and return their result.

```
const validator = abstractControl.validator({} as AbstractControl);
```

In order to update the sibling i.e `address` FormControl validity, you will have to call it's `updateValueAndValidity()`.

Another alternative could be to define validators at FormGroup level, which will be executed automatically and you don't have to manually call `updateValueAndValidity()` on any FormControl. **But**, with this approach the validation errors will be set at FormGroup level.

> since there may be dynamic controls that I don't know the name of, and
> don't want to set an observable for each of them.

If you won't be aware of control names, how exactly you will be using them within custom validator as below, where `username` FormControl is being referred?

```
this.profileGroup?.get('username')?.value
```

There is a way to call `updateValueAndValidity()` on the formControl, without explicitly specifying it's name, **BUT won't recommend it**. You can loop over the `profileGroup.controls` and execute `updateValueAndValidity` on each control, followed by profileGroup itself. You would also have to take care of passing `{onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false}` options to `updateValueAndValidity` to avoid recursion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, um
First: I am comfused why isn't this a dynamic validator?
Second: the names of the controls are in an array I guess I can get the names from there but  as I said, I don't think is optimal to crate a listener to valuechanges for each of them since there may be 1 or 20+

Comment: @Jhoan Why do you think it's a dynamic validator? Maybe that will help me to answer your query. Basically you have just created a function that takes the `control` and based on some logic either return an error object `{required: true}` or return `null` in case of no error. Maybe [this](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validator-functions) will help.

Comment: Yeah I just thought that since sometimes it is required and sometimes is not, it was a dynamic validator, thanks for letting me know my mistake there. Btw setting the Validator at group level solved my problem, thanks!